# How to split a defined string in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, discord, discord.js

I am making a leaderboard command with replit database like I have stored data for users with their id and now I want to convert that ids to mention here's my code:

```
db.list().then(keys => {
    const eachline = keys.split('/n')
    for (const line of eachline) {
      if(line.includes('Donation:')) {
        const splat = line.split('Donation:')[1]
        const final = '<@'+splat+'>';
        message.chanel.send(final);
      }}
  });
```

[image: this is the result I get from db.list()]

This is what I can get from `db.list()`
But I am getting an error on the part `const eachline = keys.split('/n')` the error is `TypeError: keys.split is not a function`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well obviously `keys` isn't a string, so you need to figure out what it *is*

```
db.list().then(keys => {
    console.log(keys);
});
```

I'd assume from the image that it's an array of strings? In which case you can probably just do:

```
db.list().then(lines => {
    for (const line of lines) {
        if(line.includes('Donation:')) {
            const splat = line.split('Donation:')[1]
            const final = '<@'+splat+'>';
            message.chanel.send(final);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! it worked  also its channel not channel 

Comment: Is their anyway to send all mentions at once?